# Unity works wrong after installing other DEs

Tags: unity, login-screen, desktop-environments

I have installed the LXDE, KDE, and GNOME environments besides unity, and also their login managers. It worked all fine, but after a while, unity starts to use the LXDE icons in the panel at the top, and the menus are somehow smaller (see the screen shot). Does anybody know why this is happening or what I can do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since all of these DEs are using the same user, some might use the same paths for e.g. icons, which would explain why you are seeing the same icons in the some DEs.
(I think .icons is used by probably more than one DE).

No idea, though how to seperate them.

Comment: So I have to create a new user for each DE? How can I make a user to use only a specific environment?